# Optional templated parameters for a function

Tags: c++, templates, optional-parameters, template-argument-deduction

I have a function in a class I want to use, whose definition is:

```
 template <typename T>
 class FooClass
 {
 /* [...] */
 public:
     template <typename TT>
     void myFunction(int a, FooClass& b, int c,
                     int d, TT optional_e = static_cast<TT>(1));
 }
```

I tried to call it this way:

```
obj.myFunction(a, b, c, d);
```

With all the arguments matching the types they should have.

However, Visual Studio throws an error at compile time:

```
C2783 : could not deduce template argument for TT
```

But if I try to call the function this way, it compiles without errors:

```
obj.myFunction(a, b, c, d, 0);
```

---

My question is, why can't I call the function without the optional parameter? How to do this?

Comment: Why do you need that optional parameter anyway? It doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: Well, if you only specify 4 parameters, there is no way for the compiler to deduce `TT` (Deduce the type from what? After all, there is no argument being passed.) I think you might want to have something akin to `template <typename TT = sometypename>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becuase [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type) can't be done by default argument; `TT` can't be deduced.

> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function default argument

You could specify the template argument explicitly:

```
obj.myFunction<int>(a, b, c, d);
```

Or give the template parameter `TT` a default type too. e.g.

```
template <typename TT = T>
void myFunction(int a, FooClass& b, int c,
                int d, TT optional_e = static_cast<TT>(1));
```

Note you still could specify the type explicitly for it.

Comment: So if use T and not TT, the optional argument can be deducted then?

Comment: @Lovy name of the template parameter does not matter at all.

Comment: Yes but T is my class template, and my function isn't static, so it should be well defined when the function is called

Comment: @Lovy It doesn't matter if it is static or not. But yes, if you make `myFunction` not a template, then it will work.

Comment: @Lovy If make it a non-template function, there's no need for template argument deduction, then it'll work fine. Or you can give `TT` a default type.

Answer (score 3):

All template arguments (e.g. `TT`) should be known in the place of the call in order to understand what `TT` is inside the function.

If you call the function the all the parameters, compiler see that type of the fourth argument is `TT` and, therefore, can deduce what `TT` is. E.g. if it's zero, then `TT = int`.

On the other hand, if you specify three parameters only, compiler have absolutely no idea about what `TT` should be. Therefore, it cannot choose which version of `myFunction` to call`- is it`myFunction`,`myFunction`or even`myFunction`?

If you want some "default" value for `TT`, you should specify that explicitly:

```
 template <typename TT = int>
 void myFunction(int a, FooClass& b, int c,
                 int d, TT optional_e = static_cast<TT>(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for these explanations